# 3D Secure v2 (SCA / PSD2) and how does it effect Magento

Tags: checkout, payment-gateway, psd2, 3d-secure

As of the 14th of September PSD2 comes into effect (more info [here](https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/12/36/3d-secure-explained))

As I understand it this means all transactions have to be 3d secure ( maybe all have to use the new 3D Secure v2).

What does this mean for our magento website checkouts, what changes are needed  (if any)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This new directive has a significant compliance impact on most payment processing services involving credit cards or bank transfers for goods & services sold to customers in the EU.

If you need to take action depends on the way each payment module is working. PayPal redirects to their own payment page, so they should take care of the PSD2 requirements. What's a bit confusing though is the following recommendation from an official Magento [newsletter](http://email2.magento.com/gh0n5qX0c20NGD0sG000RZk) sent today:

> When and/or where use of 3DS 2.0 is required, Merchants will either need to replace PayPal with Braintree or upgrade to Magento 2.3.x.

I reached out to Piotr Kaminski, who is a Lead Product Manager at Magento and he replied as follows:

> The PayPal integration that is in 1.x for some of the PayPal payment methods require use of Cardinal for 3D secure. The Cardinal integration only supports 3DS 1.0. PayPal Standard/Express/HSS Pro is not affected. All the others (PayFlow Pro, PayFlow Link, PP Payments Pro 2.0/3.0, PP Advanced) are affected and the recommednation is to switch to Braintree

Some payment integrations take credit card data directly in the Magento checkout (inline payment). Those integrations are likely those who need to be udpated if they do not yet support PSD2, yet.

Comment: It is confusing regarding PayPal, as before today's newsletter Magento stated no action was to be taken on their [blog](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/3D-Secure-2-0-changes/ba-p/136460?mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiWmprNVpXTXlZVFl3T1dRdyIsInQiOiIwTjFnMFZCc3AwTVhrMWw3OVpFemZCS3QrTmhnWDhiZzNhN2ltSEZJQ204cmRrT3kwYVV1cFRXY0hUNkpaUTRFaUM0cG1GMUdDRCt4MnJ4d0c2cDNHcXBPSTJMWkRVNXNxNHdXRVwvQ1wvc0ZwVWdGdlpGcVBCZWJSd0J3ZHRsMFVvIn0%3D). Maybe the blog post only applies to M2, but it doesn't state that anywhere.

Comment: I think that PayPal advice is just plain incorrect for M1,  if you are redirected to paypal for payment it should be ok (as they will take care of PSD2 requirements)

Comment: I reached out to Magento to be 100% sure that this is really incorrect. Will keep you posted.

Comment: More info added directly in my answer.

Comment: What Piotr Kaminski says makes sense since all payment info( for 3d version 2) is collected by paypal when you are redirected to their site. To be honest if there was a problem, I think Paypal would have warned us by now,  (they normally do when there is a up coming change that might effect payments)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **sagepay suite** use the "form" or "server" methods, you should be fine (as long as you have 3d Secure turned on),  but if you are using direct changes are needed ( 9 addional feilds need to be past). More info [here](https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/16/3d-secure-v2-what-do-customers-need-to-do)

If you are using "direct" then sagepay suite needs to be updated. Ebizmarts ( the creators of the sagepay suite extension) are working on an update and say should be ready mid August.

**Update:** Ebizmart that do the sagepay module said they will be updating there module to be compatible with 3d secure V2

> Due to delays on Sage Pay's TEST environment updates these are the new release dates for Sage Pay Suite Pro compatibility with 3D v2 + SCA:
>
> - Direct integration: August 22nd 2019.
> - Pi Integration: August 30th 2019.
>
> Please note that Form and Server integrations are already supported

**Update 2:** As pointed out in wr125 answer, The FCA have recently announced an 18-month plan extension.  So I contacted sagepay for confirmation, they said:

> Yes this new update from the FCA has relaxed the deadline so vendors will not face penalties for not using SCA until March 2021. Sage Pay will still be updating the payment gateway in time for September 14th when 3D Secure v2 will be made available but vendors do now have until March 2021 to become compliant
>
> ......Essentially 3D Secure v2 will be available from September 14th 2019 as planned but there will be no penalties for vendors not using 3D Secure v2 until March 2021, as such you have more time to update your integration

**Update 3**:  Just for completion (from sagepay)

> Yes, you can continue not using 3D Secure at all. Not passing transactions through 3D Secure at all can incur additional charges from your merchant bank however...

Answer (score 1):

The FCA have recently [announced](https://www.fca.org.uk/news/press-releases/fca-agrees-plan-phased-implementation-strong-customer-authentication) an 18-month plan (extension?) to this.

> The FCA will not take enforcement action against firms if they do not meet the relevant requirements for SCA from 14 September 2019 in areas covered by the agreed plan, where there is evidence that they have taken the necessary steps to comply with the plan. At the end of the 18-month period, the FCA expects all firms to have made the necessary changes and undertaken the required testing to apply SCA.

To me, this sounds like if you aren't ready by 14th September, but are working towards it, you'll be OK, but I could be wrong.

Does anyone have a different interpretation of this?

Comment: But payment processors like sagepay/ paypal may inforce it with all their customers ( and from when I was last talking to sagepay I'm pretty sure they said theywill from 14th of sept)

Comment: I have emailed sagepay about this to see what there policy is and will post their response here

Comment: I contacted sagepay and they have confirmed the extension ( see my updated answer), but if you are using a different payment processor I would recommend you check with them.

Answer (score 1):

I have asked this from Magento slack channel, see below:

Piotr just replied:

> *ok got some clarifiication. PayPal Standard/Express/HSS Pro is not affected. All the others (PayFlow Pro, PayFlow Link, PP Payments Pro
>   2.0/3.0, PP Advanced) are affected and the recomemdnation is to switch to Braintree*

Answer (score 1):

> The FCA have recently announced an 18-month plan (extension?) to this.
>
> > The FCA will not take enforcement action against firms if they do not meet the relevant requirements for SCA from 14 September 2019 in
> >     areas covered by the agreed plan, where there is evidence that they
> >     have taken the necessary steps to comply with the plan. At the end of
> >     the 18-month period, the FCA expects all firms to have made the
> >     necessary changes and undertaken the required testing to apply SCA.
>
> To me, this sounds like if you aren't ready by 14th September, but are
>   working towards it, you'll be OK, but I could be wrong.
>
> Does anyone have a different interpretation of this?

**NOTE**: The FCA information is only for UK based merchants! France, italy and austria plan to extend the deadline. For [germany](https://www.bafin.de/SharedDocs/Veroeffentlichungen/DE/Pressemitteilung/2019/pm_190821_PSD2_Kundenauthentifizierung.html) there is nothing planned till now - only for CC payment.