# What happens to Magento 1 websites when PSD2 effective on Sep 14th, 2019?

Tags: magento-1, psd2

Can Magento 1 site (CE + EE) comply with PSD2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do I have to do to make my Magento 1 and Magento 2 stores PSD2 Compliant?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/285515/what-do-i-have-to-do-to-make-my-magento-1-and-magento-2-stores-psd2-compliant)

Answer (score 0):

First it has been announced there as been a 18 month extension to that deadline:
https://www.fca.org.uk/news/press-releases/fca-agrees-plan-phased-implementation-strong-customer-authentication

Second yes, if the payment is taken by redirected to a payment gateway, then it would be the payment gateway that needs to comply with PSD2 (which most will be I would assume).  The only problem is if you collect the payment info and send to the payment gateway (direct method), then there are changes that need to be made to your checkout ( more info needs to be sent for 3d secure v2).  It really depend what payment method/extensions you use with your magneto install.

But to answer your question  "Can Magento 1 site (CE + EE) comply with PSD2? yes it can